# Convergence of an improper integral involving an exponential function

Tags: calculus

I am working on the following problem.

For which values of $p>0$ does the integral $$ \int_1^{\infty} p^x \; dx $$ converge?

First, I evaluated the integral as follows

$$ \lim_{b\to \infty} \int_1^b p^x \; dx = \lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{p^x}{\ln p} \biggr \rvert_1^b =\lim_{b\to \infty} \left( \frac{p^b}{\ln p}-\frac{p}{\ln p} \right)  $$

At this point, I don't know anymore how to proceed. But I know that p cannot be 1 because the denominator becomes 0. I hope somebody can enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $p=1$ divergence is clear; if $p>1$, $\log(p)>0$ and $p^b\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty}\infty$; when $0<p<1$, then $p^b\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty}0$

Answer (score 0):

If $p\geqslant1$, $p^x\geqslant1$, and therefore the integral diverges.

And if $p\in(0,1)$, then it converges, since$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{p^b}{\log p}=0.$$